# How to migrate legacy c# 2 eap code to TPL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I have Net 2.0 code that uses webservice based on `SoapHttpClientProtocol`

```
public void CommunicateWithWebservice()
{
    var success = ws.DoSomething()
    if(success)
    {
        return ws.DoSomething2();
    }
    return null;
}
```

How to convert this code to EAP (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969(v=vs.110).aspx) patten without changing it too much?

I plan to convert EAP to Task later (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622454(v=vs.110).aspx), so it will not block thread and release it to aspnet thread pool. Webservice exposes methods like `DoSomething_Async()` and event `DoSomething_Completed`. Legacy code still needs to use sync call.

I know that I can convert it to Task directly, however code needs to stay in NET 2.0. Thats why I want to change `CommunicateWithWebservice` to EAP (`CommunicateWithWebservice`, `CommunicateWithWebservice_Begin`, `CommunicateWithWebservice_Completed`) and then wrap in in task for new application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd449174(v=vs.140).aspx) to achieve what you want (simplified without error handling; you might also have to adjust the delegate parameters):

```
Task DoSomethingAsync(MyWebService ws) {
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    ws.DoSomething_Completed = delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        tcs.SetResult(null);
    };
    ws.DoSomething_Async();
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

The `TaskCompletionSource` is designed specifically to convert EAP methods to task-based methods.

Comment: My dll is using framework 2.0, so task completion source won't help.

Comment: You can use a 4.6 asssembly, reference your 2.0 assembly and still use a TCS.

Comment: Yes, my problem is that I have code that cannot yet use TCS, and I want to turn it into code that can do it.

Comment: It will probably not save you any time to change your code now. You can use a tcs once you migrate. That will also keep your code simple.

Comment: I used "yet" because I thought about call hierarchy, sorry for that. Those dlls won't be converted to 4.5 ever and that's why I want to introduce async without effort.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that I can convert it to Task directly, however code needs to stay in NET 2.0. Thats why I want to change CommunicateWithWebservice to EAP (CommunicateWithWebservice, CommunicateWithWebservice_Begin, CommunicateWithWebservice_Completed) and then wrap in in task for new application.

Use

```
AsyncCallback
```

It is a delegate that allows you to define your own BeginXXX and EndXXX methods.

On BeginInvoke you get `IAsyncResult` on that you have `IsCompleted` property to indicate if the operation has been completed.

Once you have this setup you can easily wrap Begin and End methods into `Task.Factory.FromAsync()` method.

Once wrapped up into Task, I would recomend to use async/await.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't see how I can use this. My `CommunicateWithWebservice_Completed` is event, so I have start method and event. I think that I will have to start new thread myself and implement wrapper class that uses `IAsyncResult` and waits for event with `AutoResetEvent`. Am I correct?